# how to send a file as a request as a raw http request body

Tags: json, http-post, jmeter

I have working http request call with JSON body. WHat I want to do is to use the same content as an external file. For this I have used "send files with the request" function, without using multi-part because our server doesn't support that. I tried with or without parameter name or MIME type and the result is the same 400. The same call is working if instead I use the JSON in the body. 
File location is good, i double checked that. THe actual content of the file is not displayed in the request.

Any ideas?

Comment: If answer is OK, you should accept it so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

> Name of the file to send. If left blank, JMeter does not send a file, if filled in, JMeter automatically sends the request as a multipart form request.
>   **If it is a POST or PUT or PATCH request and there is a single file whose 'Parameter name' attribute (below) is omitted, then the file is sent as the entire body of the request**, i.e. no wrappers are added. This allows arbitrary bodies to be sent. This functionality is present for POST requests after version 2.2, and also for PUT requests after version 2.3. See below for some further information on parameter handling.

Comment: How about writing an example ? I' m trying  `{ post:  {title:"Hello", file: ${filepath}, 
visible:false  }
}` , where filepath is my parameter name, and that text i place on the value field of an empty name parameter

Comment: Show your sampler configuration. If you want examples, download JMETER 2.10 RC2 (see http://t.co/E3NE3rWGmu), use new Template feature it will show you how to do.

Comment: Which template has the File post with json example ?

Comment: Meanwhile I've added a proxy under jmeter and notice the request seems to go only with file content

Comment: do you mean you have an attachment ?

Comment: yes, I do have an attachment, or so I believe, since I refer the file data within my json file, and it is a multipart request

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jmeter function **__fileToString** for that:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString